# post data with ajax and jquery to other page

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

How do I sent data from one page to another with `$.ajax` and go to that other page?
If I try the codes below I only get an error on the second page (`watch-video.php`).

I use this code on the `videos.php` page

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "watch-video.php",
            data: {video: "test"},

            success: function(msg)
            {
                                $(location).attr('href',"watch-video.php");

            }
        });
```

I use this code on the `watch-video.php` page

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['video'];
?>

<html>
<body>

<?php echo $name; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

---

This gives me the same error on the `watch-video.php page`. The error is about this line:

```
    <?php
$name=$_POST['video'];
?>
```

The error I get is this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: video in `C:\wamp\www\website\watch-video.php on line 26`
```

I want to submit something to another page, and go to that page but without a form. It has to be done when I click on a div:

```
 $("#gvidbalk").click(function(){
```

It is for something like youtube, if you click on a video image you will go to another page where you can watch that video.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'insert.php',
    data:'name='+name+'&pass='+pass,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

If you this use method you can easy pass data. It is very simple and easy.

Answer (score -1):

You could do:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "watch-video.php",
        data: {video: "test"},

        success: function(msg)
        {
                           window.location.href = "watch-video.php";

        }
    });
```